# How do you create a textbox in C++ and DirectX 9 for games?

Tags: c++, directx

I'm currently working on the menu for a game and I've tried searching for information on how to create a textbox within the menu for some particular options such as the name of the player, and I haven't found any useful information about it.

I am using DirectInput for the keyboard input for the game itself, but it seems that would be far too 'over-sensitive' for typing into a textbox. How would I create a textbox that could reliably accept input?

Comment: I'm not completely sure on this, but would a call to `CreateWindow` with the `Edit` class work with directx? I remember not being able to do layered windows due to it using the graphics card, but I don't know if it's the same for controls.

Comment: Thanks for that. I just tested it, and it seems to work with displaying. How would I get the input string or character string from the `Edit` window?

Comment: `char text [maxLength]; SendMessage (hTextbox, WM_GETTEXT, maxLength, (WPARAM)text);` That's off the top of my head, but I'm sure you can easily find any small errors in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to game UIs, they rely upon non-OS primitives so that they can be styled and flow exactly as the game designers intend. Also using non-OS primitives allows better integration with the game engine. A popular open source game UI toolkit is [CEGUI](http://www.cegui.org.uk/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). If you want a UI toolkit for debug purposes I'd look at [AntTweakBar](http://www.antisphere.com/Wiki/tools%3aanttweakbar). And finally a UI toolkit provided by the DirectX SDK is the DXUT (Look at DX9 SDK samples for the DXUT 9 version).

Comment: Would it be possible for you to provide some examples of those UI toolkits being used to create and manage textboxes?

Comment: No, I think this is this point where you visit said sites and do some digging yourself.